# Excel- If multiple cells in a range are blank, return an answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel (365 edition), I want to have a formula determine whether in a range of 5 cells, 3 of those cells are blank. If there are 3 cells, I want it to display `INELIGIBLE`, if there are fewer than 3 blank cells, I want it to display `ELIGIBLE`.

The values in the cells with data in them shall range from 1-6, so I'm not sure whether a `COUNT` function is actually appropriate.

I tried using the `IF` and `COUNT` functions similar to another question on superuser, but it returns `#NAME?` using the formula:

> =IF(COUNT('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!F5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!I5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!L5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!O5)>2,ELIGIBLE,INELIGIBLE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF((COUNTBLANK('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5)+COUNTBLANK('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5)+COUNTBLANK('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5)+COUNTBLANK('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5)+COUNTBLANK('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5))>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")`
For your specific situation, that is.

As a more general answer.
`=IF((COUNTBLANK(D3)+COUNTBLANK(D4)+COUNTBLANK(D5)+COUNTBLANK(D6)+COUNTBLANK(D7))>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")`

Simple to do. Use COUNTBLANK instead of count. 
What I'm doing is counting how many blank cells there are and adding them up. I like the phrasing of countblank to make your point, but you could also use ISBLANK to accomplish this. Something like 
`=IF((ISBLANK(D3)+ISBLANK(D4)+ISBLANK(D5)+ISBLANK(D6)+ISBLANK(D7)>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")` Going from the fact that "TRUE" resolves to one, then summing those ones will work just like COUNTBLANK in this regard.

Comment: `COUNTBLANK` [accepts a range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countblank-HP005209028.aspx), you don't need to repeat it for each cell. `=IF(COUNTBLANK(D3:D7)>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")` would suffice.

Comment: right, but in the example they didn't use contiguous cells, so I split it out like they would have to

Answer (score 1):

Your original formula will work if you put the text values that are returned by the IF() statement into double quotes. The #Name? error means that Excel does not recognise ELIGIBLE and INELIGIBLE as Excel commands or defined names.

If the cells contain numbers, use your formula above. I only added the quotes around the last two words.

```
=IF(COUNT('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!F5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!I5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!L5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!O5)>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")
```

Or you can use CountA() instead, which works for both:

```
=IF(COUNTA('GRADE 11 DATA'!C5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!F5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!I5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!L5,'GRADE 11 DATA'!O5)>2,"ELIGIBLE","INELIGIBLE")
```